# What is the Bi-affine plane

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, reference-request

I want to know the definition of the Bi-affine plane. In an article it says that semi-symmetric plane is same as bi-affine plane. But I want to the exact definition and axioms. Also There are two types of Bi-affine planes Type I and Type II. It defines only in one paper, that is in German, but I don't know German and difficult to translate with math symbols (using google and other online translations).

Can you help me to find  the definitions of the Bi-affine plane of type I and II, pls..

If there are any references, pls tell me...

Thanks.

Comment: May I suggest you to provide a link to the paper in quetion? A few of our users (including me) are capable of German and might be able to help this way.

Comment: Geometriae Dedicata, Volume 4, Issue 2-4, 1975. Manfred Oehler's "Endliche biaffine Inzidenzebenen" pg:419-436.

Comment: Can anyone help me....

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to springerlink right now. Can you provide an excerpt containig the term (preferrably the first occurence)? The translation should be somewhat like "bi-affine incidence plane"... [this](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01220475) might refer to the same topic in english (not sure though)

Comment: yes, that is the topic. But that is not same paper you given.

Comment: I don't know how to attach a file.

Comment: @AlexR ; Here is the doc:" http://www.scribd.com/doc/203384110/art-3A10-1007-2FBF00148773" . Thanks

Comment: A Bi-affine incidence plane is a $h$-affine incidence plane with $h=2$. Is that what you were looking for? (bi is the greek prefix for two).

Comment: A Bi-affine incidence plane is a $h$-affine incidence plane with $h=2$. Is that what you were looking for? (bi is the greek prefix for two).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The very first page defines it:

> Eine Inzidenzstruktur $\mathfrak A$, die (A1), (A2) und (A3,h) für eine natürliche Zahl $h$ erfüllt, heißt $h$-affine Inzidenzebene. Sind $\mathfrak P, \mathfrak G$ endlich, so heiß $\mathfrak A$ endlich. Eine $2$-affine Ebene heißt auch *biaffin*

In other words:
A bi-affine (incidence) plane is a structure satisfiying
$(A1), (A2)$ and $(A3,2)$:
$$\begin{align*}
(A1)\qquad & \text{for each } P, Q\in \mathfrak P \ \exists!\ g\in\mathfrak G \text{ such that } g \text{ incides with both } P,Q \\
(A2)\qquad & \text{There are } P,Q,R \in \mathfrak P \text{ such that no } g\in\mathfrak G \text{ incides with all three}\\
(A3,2)\qquad & \forall (P,g)\in\mathfrak P\times \mathfrak G: \ 1\le\pi(P,g) \le 2
\end{align*}$$

---

Definition 6 defines a $w$-line by $O(g) = n$ and a $v$-line by $O(g) = N$(where $N$ is the *order* and $n$ is the *suborder*)
Which is given in eqn. (5) / Definition 2 by
$$N = \max_{g\in\mathfrak G} O(g), \qquad n=\min_{g\in\mathfrak G} O(G)$$

---

Definition 7 defines a **Type I** biaffine plane to be one such that every point has a $w$-line inciding it.
Definition 8 defines a **Type II** biaffine plane to be one such that every point has a $v$-line inciding it.

Comment: @Ryan happy to help. If this solved your question, please mark it as answered. If not, feel free to ask for further clarification.

Comment: I need to know about the Bi-affine plane Type II, it was in. Can you given me a little translation abt that. Thanks.

Comment: @Ryan I've added all the details, you should be able to expand the definitions now to obtain the big picture.

Comment: Thanks AlexR, but I don't know how to say "answered".

Comment: @Ryan To the left of the post where the up and down arrows are, there is also a checkmark. You click that and it's done ;) See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for some tutorial-like introduction texts to this forum.

Answer (score -1):

I read one paper that defined bi-affine as follows:
   We say $f(u,x)$ is bi-affine if the function $f(u,x)$ is affine for any $x$ and the function is affine for any fixed $u$.

Dimitris Bertsimas, Vishal Gupta, etc., "Data-driven robust optimization".